# Loading data from another thread, is it thread safe?

Tags: java

Is loading data from another thread; thread safe?

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Thread threadOne = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            loadContacts();
        }

    });

    Thread threadTwo = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            loadDefinitions();//Loads definitions
        }

    });

    threadOne.start();
    threadTwo.start();

}
```

The code is showing that the List will be loaded using thread 1 and the List will be loaded on thread 2. Is this thread safe? if we have a final thread for game logics accessing both lists?

Answer (score 0):

This is only safe if you make sure the final thread, which accesses both lists, waits until both `threadOne` and `threadTwo` have completed, e.g. call `threadOne.join()` and`threadTwo.join()` before trying to read from the lists.

If you don't want the final thread to wait, then you will have to add some synchronization, to ensure thread safety.

Comment: Thanks for the reply